# glob php - return all types of images from directory

Tags: php, image, include, carousel, glob

I have a php function to grab images from a folder for a carousel and build the carousel on those images.
I have a thumbnail folder and a main img folder.

**My question is**, how can I modify this code or what to add in order to recognise more image file types and not only jpg. I want to support png, gif and jpg.

My code is below:

```
<?php $thumbs = glob("img/thumb/*.jpg"); ?>
    <?php
    if(count($thumbs)) {
      natcasesort($thumbs);
      foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {
      ?>
          <li class="item">
              <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/large/<?php echo basename($thumb) ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" width="100%" alt="" />
              </a>
          </li> 

    <?php
        }} else {
          echo "Sorry, no images to display!";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Change this line :

```
glob("img/thumb/*.jpg")
```

to

```
glob("img/thumb/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)
```

It's important to have no spaces in the list of endings.

Comment: Thank you! Leaning new things everyday!

Comment: oops.. spoke too soon! tested and didn't work! I thought it had.. :(

Comment: could you tell me the error?

Comment: Just doesn't recognise any file now! It displays the 'else' echo code. (No images to display)

Comment: It's important to have no spaces in the list of endings.