# How to display all photos in a folder in a folder?

Tags: php, html, image, loops

I have stumbled upon a problem while developing a simple website. I wanted to know how could I access and display all images stored in a folder inside another folder ? 
Thanks for the input! =)

Comment: `readdir`, `scandir` etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309554/glob-php-return-all-types-of-images-from-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `scandir()` function to read all files in a folder then filter that files and get only images from theme

```
<?php
$folder = 'images';
$files = scandir($folder);
$types = array('jpg','png','gif');

foreach($files as $file) {
   $exp = explode('.', $file);
   $ex = end($exp);
   if(in_array($ex , $types)) {
     echo '<img src="'. $folder .'/'.$file.'" />';
    }
 }
 ?>
```

or use `glob()` to read only images in a dir the line of code below gets all `.jpg` images

```
$files = glob("images/*.jpg");
```