# PHP show specific directory files

Tags: php

Trying to only show specific files to my page. I'm returning a thumbs.db file, which is invisible in the directory.  I need to only show pdf, docx, or xls files.

```
 <?php
   function returnEmpdisDocs()
   {
     $dir = "empdis/docs/";
     $ffs = scandir($dir);

     foreach($ffs as $ff)
     {
       if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
       {
         $filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $ff);    
         echo "<li><a download href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a></li>";
       }
     }
   }
   returnEmpdisDocs();
 ?>
```

My question is: what can I add to the above code to only include pdf, docx, and xls files?

Comment: exactly what you're doing: add whatever `if` tests you need to filter out what you do/don't want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309554/glob-php-return-all-types-of-images-from-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file listing multiple file extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591530/php-file-listing-multiple-file-extensions)

Comment: `if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && preg_match('#(pdf|docx|xls)$#',$ff))`

Comment: @JOUM - where do I put that IF statement?

Comment: extend that what you have :)

Comment: @JOUM - Got it.  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.  Adding your suggestion in my FOREACH is what solved my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

`if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')`

and use that:

`if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && preg_match('#\.(pdf|docx|xls)$#',$ff))`

the regex `\.(pdf|docx|xls)$` tests that a string ends with one of the given words

little update: better test for real extentions (noted by Patrick), i added `\.`

Comment: Note that this solution does not explicitly check the extension (or file-type). It simply checks what's at the end of the file name.  So a file named `mypdf` (with no extension) would pass this check. As would `example.notxls`

Comment: Subsequent edits have addressed the issue mentioned in my earlier comment.